# json data populate and multiselection to get Ids

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I have to post a JSON and in response get user Id and many more things.I have added it to an array and populate my tableview. like this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ModelClass * model = __arrayForContacts[indexPath.row];

  MYcustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}
```

now, I have applied multi-selection to my tableview.I want to get the user id from multi-selected row.I want it to post as request in next JSON parsing.How can i achieve this, any help would be thankful.

Comment: did you declare any property for multiselect in ModelClass ?

Comment: can you explain me why it would be needed.?

Comment: check my answer . you need to declared bool propery in your model class  it named is isSelected for track your selection .

Comment: __arrayForContacts tis is my array which contains userId,userName,UserImage...how can i achieve only userId of selected rows from tis and add it into an array.

Comment: did you declared isSelected property ?

Comment: m not getting u properly ,what do u want me to do ...with that..?

Comment: if you declared then check my updated answer.

Comment: add this line in  your 'ModelClass'  and follow my answer : @property (nonatomic)BOOL isSelected;

Comment: where i have to put this code to attain results.

Comment: in your mode class add this line : @property (nonatomic)BOOL isSelected

Comment: m asking about nspredicate where to put that ...?

Comment: at where you need to post this userid .

Comment: can u also explain me how to post an array in JSON request,does i have to make it nsdata

Comment: you need to json encoded fromat  which i have explained in updated answer .jsonString is the your final string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In tableview's didselect method you need to set as below

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    yourobjectClass *objCookBook = [arrCookBook objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    objCookBook.isSelected = !objCookBook.isSelected;
    //[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    //[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];// uncomment above line if you want to reload table
}
```

You can get as below :

// isSelected is your flag for selection

```
     NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isSelected == 1"];
      NSArray *arrSelected = [arrCookBook filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
     if (arrSelected.count > 0) {
       NSlog(@"%@",[arrSelected valueForKey:@"userId"]); // replace your id name and post it to json 

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[arrSelected valueForKey:@"userId"] options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
    NSString *JsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }
```

Comment: why to keep track for selection.When indexPathsForSelectedRows provide all the rows which are selected.

Comment: because it is a easy way if we want to post json at end . if you want to use indexPathsForSelectedRows then you need do work more at end .

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan can you explain it through indexPathForSelectedRows .I am doing and in between .

Comment: i am trying to say that both require work to do.So its better to use already implemented thing. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to apply custom multi selection so try this, it's never failed.
follow steps:-

1. add new value in each & every dictionary of array using loop
   when you get response. like that

> for j in 0 ..< arrList.count{
>       let dictList = arrList.objectAtIndex(j) as! NSMutableDictionary
>       dictList.setObject("0", forKey: "val")
>        arrList.replaceObjectAtIndex(j, withObject: dictList)
>       }
>       tblView.reloadData

2. apply condition in **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

> let dictList = arrList.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as!
>       NSMutableDictionary let val = dictList.objectForKey("attribute_option_list")  as! String
>       if val == "0"{
>       "uncheck"
>       }else{
>       "check"
>       }

3. also apply condition in **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** with change value of val key in particular index dictionary

> let dictList = arrList.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as!
>           NSMutableDictionary
>       let val = dictList.objectForKey("attribute_option_list")  as! String
>           if val == "0"{
>           dictList.setObject("1", forKey: "val") 
>           }else{
>           dictList.setObject("0", forKey: "val") 
>           }
>       arrList.replaceObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row, withObject: dictList)
>       tblView.reloadData()

**Don't forgot reload table & use proper condition with check uncheck & value of key**

**You can also return selected data to server in json formate**